# React, Formik Field Arrays - mapping over repeatable fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, formik

I'm trying to figure out how to use Formik field arrays in a react project.

I have one form (glossary) that has 3 Field Arrays within it (one for each of relatedTerms, templates and referenceMaterials).

Each of the field arrays is set out in a separate component. When I only used one of them, I had this working. Adding the next one has caused a problem that I can't solve.

My form has:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {render} from 'react-dom';

import { Link  } from 'react-router-dom';
import firebase, {firestore} from '../../../../firebase';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import {
  Button,
  LinearProgress,
  MenuItem,
  FormControl,
  Divider,
  InputLabel,
  FormControlLabel,
  TextField,
  Typography,
  Box,
  Grid,
  Checkbox,
  Dialog,
  DialogActions,
  DialogContent,
  DialogContentText,
  DialogTitle,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import MuiTextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';


import {
  Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage, FieldArray,
} from 'formik';


import * as Yup from 'yup';
import {
  Autocomplete,
  ToggleButtonGroup,
  AutocompleteRenderInputParams,
} from 'formik-material-ui-lab';
import {
  fieldToTextField,
  TextFieldProps,
  Select,
  Switch,
} from 'formik-material-ui';

import RelatedTerms from "./RelatedTerms";
import ReferenceMaterials from "./ReferenceMaterials";
import Templates from "./Templates";

const allCategories = [
    {value: 'one', label: 'One'},
    {value: 'two', label: 'Two'},
    
];


function UpperCasingTextField(props: TextFieldProps) {
    const {
      form: {setFieldValue},
      field: {name},
    } = props;
    const onChange = React.useCallback(
      event => {
        const {value} = event.target;
        setFieldValue(name, value ? value.toUpperCase() : '');
      },
      [setFieldValue, name]
    );
    return <MuiTextField {...fieldToTextField(props)} onChange={onChange} />;
  }

  function Glossary(props) {
    const { classes } = props;
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [isSubmitionCompleted, setSubmitionCompleted] = useState(false);
    
    function handleClose() {
      setOpen(false);
    }
  
    function handleClickOpen() {
      setSubmitionCompleted(false);
      setOpen(true);
    }
  
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
          <Button
              // component="button"
              color="primary"
              onClick={handleClickOpen}
              style={{ float: "right"}}
              variant="outlined"
          >
              Create Term
          </Button>
        <Dialog
          open={open}
          onClose={handleClose}
          aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
        >
          {!isSubmitionCompleted &&
            <React.Fragment>
              <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Create a defined term</DialogTitle>
              <DialogContent>
                <DialogContentText>
                   
                </DialogContentText>
                <Formik
                  initialValues={{ term: "",  definition: "",  category: [],  context: "", relatedTerms: [], templates: [], referenceMaterials: [] }}
                  
                  onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
                     setSubmitting(true);
                     firestore.collection("glossary").doc().set({
                      ...values,
                      createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
                      })
                    .then(() => {
                      setSubmitionCompleted(true);
                    });
                  }}
  
                  validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
                    term: Yup.string()
                      .required('Required'),
                    definition: Yup.string()
                      .required('Required'),
                    category: Yup.string()
                      .required('Required'),
                    context: Yup.string()
                      .required("Required"),
                    // relatedTerms: Yup.string()
                    //   .required("Required"),
                    // templates: Yup.string()
                    //   .required("Required"),
                    // referenceMaterials: Yup.string()
                    //   .required("Required"),
                      
  
                  })}
                >
                  {(props) => {
                    const {
                      values,
                      touched,
                      errors,
                      dirty,
                      isSubmitting,
                      handleChange,
                      handleBlur,
                      handleSubmit,
                      handleReset,
                    } = props;
                    return (
                      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <TextField
                          label="Term"
                          name="term"
                        //   className={classes.textField}
                          value={values.term}
                          onChange={handleChange}
                          onBlur={handleBlur}
                          helperText={(errors.term && touched.term) && errors.term}
                          margin="normal"
                          style={{ width: "100%"}}
                        />
  
                        <TextField
                          label="Meaning"
                          name="definition"
                          multiline
                          rows={4}
                        //   className={classes.textField}
                          value={values.definition}
                          onChange={handleChange}
                          onBlur={handleBlur}
                          helperText={(errors.definition && touched.definition) && errors.definition}
                          margin="normal"
                          style={{ width: "100%"}}
                        />
  
                        
                        
                        <TextField
                          label="In what context is this term used?"
                          name="context"
                        //   className={classes.textField}
                          multiline
                          rows={4}
                          value={values.context}
                          onChange={handleChange}
                          onBlur={handleBlur}
                          helperText={(errors.context && touched.context) && errors.context}
                          margin="normal"
                          style={{ width: "100%"}}
                        />
                        
  
                        
                        <Box margin={1}>
                          <Field
                            name="category"
                            multiple
                            component={Autocomplete}
                            options={allCategories}
                            getOptionLabel={(option: any) => option.label}
                            style={{width: '100%'}}
                            renderInput={(params: AutocompleteRenderInputParams) => (
                              <MuiTextField
                                {...params}
                                error={touched['autocomplete'] && !!errors['autocomplete']}
                                helperText={touched['autocomplete'] && errors['autocomplete']}
                                label="Category"
                                variant="outlined"
                              />
                            )}
                          />
                        </Box>     
                        <Divider style={{marginTop: "20px", marginBottom: "20px"}}></Divider> 
                        <Box>
                        <Typography variant="subtitle2">
                          Add a related term
                        </Typography>
                        <FieldArray name="relatedTerms" component={RelatedTerms} />
                        </Box>
                        <Box>
                        <Typography variant="subtitle2">
                          Add a reference document
                        </Typography>
                        <FieldArray name="referenceMaterials" component={ReferenceMaterials} />
                        </Box>
                        <Box>
                        <Typography variant="subtitle2">
                          Add a template
                        </Typography>
                        <FieldArray name="templates" component={Templates} />
                        </Box>
                        
                        <DialogActions>
                          <Button
                            type="button"
                            className="outline"
                            onClick={handleReset}
                            disabled={!dirty || isSubmitting}
                          >
                            Reset
                          </Button>
                          <Button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
                            Submit
                          </Button>
                          {/* <DisplayFormikState {...props} /> */}
                        </DialogActions>
                      </form>
                    );
                  }}
                </Formik>
              </DialogContent>
            </React.Fragment>
          }
          {isSubmitionCompleted &&
            <React.Fragment>
              <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Thanks!</DialogTitle>
              <DialogContent>
                <DialogContentText>
                  We appreciate your contribution.
                </DialogContentText>
                <DialogActions>
                  <Button
                    type="button"
                    className="outline"
                    onClick={handleClose}
                  >
                    Close
                    </Button>
                  {/* <DisplayFormikState {...props} /> */}
                </DialogActions>
              </DialogContent>
            </React.Fragment>}
        </Dialog>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }



export default Glossary;
```

Then, each subform is as follows (but replacing relatedTerms for templates or referenceMaterials).

```
import React from "react";
import { Formik, Field } from "formik";
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import {
  Button,
  LinearProgress,
  MenuItem,
  FormControl,
  InputLabel,
  FormControlLabel,
  TextField,
  Typography,
  Box,
  Grid,
  Checkbox,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import MuiTextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import {
  fieldToTextField,
  TextFieldProps,
  Select,
  Switch,
} from 'formik-material-ui';


const initialValues = {
  title: "",
  description: "",
  source: ""
};



class RelatedTerms extends React.Component {
  render() {
   
    const {form: parentForm, ...parentProps} = this.props;

    return (
      <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        render={({ values, setFieldTouched }) => {
          return (
            <div>
              {parentForm.values.relatedTerms.map((_notneeded, index) => {
                return (
                  <div key={index}>
                    
                              <TextField
                                label="Title"
                                name={`relatedTerms.${index}.title`}
                                placeholder=""
                                // className="form-control"
                                // value={values.title}
                                margin="normal"
                                style={{ width: "100%"}}
                                onChange={e => {
                                  parentForm.setFieldValue(
                                    `relatedTerms.${index}.title`,
                                    e.target.value
                                  );
                                }}
                              >
                              </TextField>
                            

                            <TextField
                              label="Description"
                              name={`relatedTerms.${index}.description`}
                              placeholder="Describe the relationship"
                              // value={values.description}
                              onChange={e => {
                                parentForm.setFieldValue(
                                  `relatedTerms.${index}.description`,
                                  e.target.value
                                );
                              }}
                              // onBlur={handleBlur}
                              // helperText={(errors.definition && touched.definition) && errors.definition}
                              margin="normal"
                              style={{ width: "100%"}}
                            />
                          
                            
                          
                            
                          <Button
                            variant="outlined"
                            color="secondary"    
                            size="small"
                            onClick={() => parentProps.remove(index)}
                          >
                            Remove this term
                          </Button>
                        
                  </div>
                );
              })}
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                color="secondary"
                size="small"
                style={{ marginTop: "5vh"}}
                onClick={() => parentProps.push(initialValues)}
              >
                Add a related term
              </Button>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default RelatedTerms;
```

Then when I try to render the data submitted in the form, I have:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import ImpactMetricsForm from "./Form";
import firebase, { firestore } from "../../../../firebase.js";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import ExpansionPanel from '@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanel';
import ExpansionPanelDetails from '@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanelDetails';
import ExpansionPanelSummary from '@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanelSummary';
import ExpansionPanelActions from '@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanelActions';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    marginTop: '8vh',
    marginBottom: '5vh'
  },
  heading: {
    fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(15),
  },
  heading2: {
    fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(15),
    fontWeight: "500",
    marginTop: '3vh',
    marginBottom: '1vh',
    
  },
  secondaryHeading: {
    fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(15),
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
    textTransform: 'capitalize'
  },
  icon: {
    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
    height: 20,
    width: 20,
  },
  details: {
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  column: {
    flexBasis: '20%',
  },

  columnBody: {
    flexBasis: '70%',
  },
  
  helper: {
    borderLeft: `2px solid ${theme.palette.divider}`,
    padding: theme.spacing(1, 2),
  },
  link: {
    color: theme.palette.primary.main,
    textDecoration: 'none',
    '&:hover': {
      textDecoration: 'underline',
    },
  },
}));

const Title = {
    fontFamily: "'Montserrat', sans-serif",
    fontSize: "4vw",
    marginBottom: '2vh'
};

const Subhead = {
    fontFamily: "'Montserrat', sans-serif",
    fontSize: "calc(2vw + 1vh + .5vmin)",
    marginBottom: '2vh',
    marginTop: '8vh',
    width: "100%"
};

function useGlossaryTerms() {
    const [glossaryTerms, setGlossaryTerms] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
      firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("glossary")
        .orderBy('term')
        .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
          const glossaryTerms = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
            id: doc.id,
            ...doc.data(),
          }))
          setGlossaryTerms(glossaryTerms)
        })
    }, [])
    return glossaryTerms
  }

  

const GlossaryTerms = () => {

    const glossaryTerms = useGlossaryTerms()
    const classes = useStyles();

    return ( 
        <div style={{ marginLeft: "3vw"}}>
            <div className={classes.root}>
            
            {glossaryTerms.map(glossaryTerm => {
                return (
                <ExpansionPanel defaultcollapsed>
                <ExpansionPanelSummary
                    expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                    aria-controls="panel1c-content"
                    id="panel1c-header"
                >
                    <div className={classes.column}>
                    <Typography className={classes.heading}>{glossaryTerm.term}</Typography>
                    </div>
                    <div className={classes.column}>
                    
                    {glossaryTerm.category.map(category => (
                        <Typography className={classes.secondaryHeading}>
                        {category.label}
                        </Typography>
                    )

                    )}
                    
                    </div>
                </ExpansionPanelSummary>
                <ExpansionPanelDetails className={classes.details}>
                    
                    <div className={clsx(classes.columnBody)}>
                    <div>    
                        <Typography variant="subtitle2" className={classes.heading2}>Meaning</Typography>
                        <Typography>{glossaryTerm.definition}</Typography>
                    </div>
                        <div>
                        <Typography variant="subtitle2" className={classes.heading2}>Context</Typography>
                        <div>
                            <Typography>{glossaryTerm.context}</Typography>
                        </div>
                    
                    <div className={clsx(classes.helper)}>
                    <div>
                    <Typography variant="caption">Related Terms</Typography>
                        
                        {glossaryTerm.relatedTerms.map(relatedTerm => (
                            
                            <Typography variant="body2" className="blogParagraph" key={relatedTerm.id}>
                            {relatedTerm.title}
                            </Typography>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                    <div>    
                        <Typography variant="caption" >Related Templates</Typography>
                        {glossaryTerm.templates.map(template => (
                            
                            <Typography variant="body2" className="blogParagraph" key={template.id}>
                            {template.title}
                            </Typography>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <Typography variant="caption">Related Reference Materials</Typography>
                        {glossaryTerm.referenceMaterials.map(referenceMaterial => (
                            
                            <Typography variant="body2" className="blogParagraph" key={referenceMaterial.id}>
                            {referenceMaterial.title}
                            </Typography>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </ExpansionPanelDetails>
                <Divider />
                <ExpansionPanelActions>
                   {glossaryTerm.attribution}
                    
                </ExpansionPanelActions>
                </ExpansionPanel>

            )
        })}
            </div>
            
        </div>   

     );
}
 
export default GlossaryTerms;
```

When I try this using only the relatedTerms field array, I can submit data in the form and render the list.

When I add in the next two Field Array components for Templates and ReferenceMaterials, I get an error that says:

> TypeError: glossaryTerm.referenceMaterials.map is not a function

Each of the 3 field arrays is a duplicate, where I've only changed the name of the value in the main form. You can see from the screen shot attached that the data within each map from the form fields is the same for each of relatedTerms, templates and referenceMaterials. When I comment out templates and referenceMaterials from the rendered output, everything renders properly. When I comment out relatedTerms and try to render either templates or referenceMaterials, I get the error I reported.

[image]

If I remove the templates and referenceMaterials map statements from the rendered output, I can use the form with all 3 field arrays in it. They save properly in firebase. I just can't display them using the method that works for relatedTerms.

Comment: please create a code sandbox if possible.

Comment: Hi @VarunS - thanks for taking a look at this. It isn't really a problem I can recreate in sandbox without a firestore. The records from each of the 3 repeatable form field arrays save correctly into firestore. I cannot use anything other than relatedTerms when trying to read them back. They each have the same attributes (title & id), but only relatedTerms renders without the map error I reported. I can complete all 3 form fields in the form. I cannot render the attributes saved in templates or referenceMaterials. I've added a screenshot of the document profile in firestore to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything seems ok with your code. I suspect that the problem is in the data coming from firebase in `useGlossaryTerms`, some entries in the `glossary` collection may not have `referenceMaterials` or `templates` fields (maybe from a previous form submit that did not have those yet).

You could :

1. Run a migration script on the collection to add defaults for those fields if they don't exist.
2. Add defaults on client side :

---

```
firebase
.firestore()
.collection("glossary")
.orderBy('term')
.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
  const glossaryTerms = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
    const data = doc.data();
    return {
      id: doc.id,
      ...data,
      referenceMaterials: data.referenceMaterials || [],
      templates: data.templates || []
    };
  }
  setGlossaryTerms(glossaryTerms)
})
```

3. On the client side, check if those fields exists before rendering :

---

```
{
  glossaryTerm.templates ? (
    <div>    
      <Typography variant="caption" >Related Templates</Typography>
      {glossaryTerm.templates.map(template => (
          
          <Typography variant="body2" className="blogParagraph" key={template.id}>
          {template.title}
          </Typography>
      ))}
    </div>
  ) : null
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate this. Yes, you're right. One of the entries was blank. I thought the null was a default as a standard convention. Thanks a lot!